# Spring boot junit test cannot get command line argument (Eclipse - STS)

Tags: junit, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, spring-tool-suite

I did a Spring Boot application, and use some command line arguments. I read them in services like

```
@Value("${v}")
private String vertical;
```

Application works and see value passed from command line. I added same command line arguments to all JUnit tests run configurations

> --spring.profiles.active=development --m=keyword --v=Healthcare --i=keyword_update.json

[image: jUnit run config]

But when I try to run test it crashes with message, that means application context cannot get command line attribute:

> 2016-05-28 17:16:00.924 ERROR 4204 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplicat ion               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean wit h name 'application': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested excepti on is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowir e field: healthjobs.service.Catalog
>   healthjobs.app.Application.catalog; nested e xception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creat
>   ing bean with name 'catalogImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies
>   failed; ne sted exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could  not
>   autowire field: healthjobs.service.CatalogPage
>   healthjobs.service.CatalogIm pl.catalogPage; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreati onException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'catalogPageImpl': Injection of autow ired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory. BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.lang.String health
>   jobs.service.CatalogPageImpl.vertical; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgu mentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'v'
>   in string value "${v}"

Why? How to run tests with command line arguments in spring boot?

PS full stack trace appears too long to attach here. When I run mvn package I get same error about test, but mvn run config does not have ability to input command line arguments. My environment:

> Spring Tool Suite  Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE Build Id: 201511261048
>   Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)

Comment: Can you verify what the actual arguments look like on the process that get launched. I'm not sure what is going on but it may help to see exactly what arguments do end up getting passed to the process. You can see these arguments by as follows: 1. open debug perspective/view. 2. in debug view right-click on the process (terminated or still running, doesn't matter). 3. Select 'properties'. 4. Take note of the text in 'Command Line' box. It shows exactly how the process was launched.

Comment: This isn't really an answer as I'm not so sure about this... but I suspect you can't pass arguments this way because when you "Run as JUnit" you are in fact launching Eclipse's JUnit test runner, not your application itself. And the JUnit runner simply doesn't parse arguments the same way that a spring boot app does.

Comment: Hi. I tried to check arguments from debug mode, but cannot do this. When I put break point in my test class or main app class (it mentioned in test class as @SpringApplicationConfiguration) application crashes before any program steps. So it looks like Spring not see parameter (cannot inject it) and crash before my application run. About second - may be you right. I was able to run tests, but instead of command line I put properties in my test resources folder file: test.properties. I can accept it for now, but it could be that I need different command line arguments for different test cases.

Comment: You don't have to put breakpoints to check the CL argumens. As I said you can check them *after* the program is already crashed. The debug view still has an item for the crashed process on which you can see the commandline arguments in its 'properties'. Anyhoo... I was going to suggest try to put a properties file in your resources folder instead. Glad you figured that out yourself and it works.

Comment: Now I find what are you told about in debug perspective:
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner --spring.profiles.active=development --m=keyword --v=Healthcare --i=keyword_update.json 
is it helps somehow?

Comment: It confirms what I thought. The 'app' you are running with "Run As Junit" is eclipse's test runner. So it doesn't interpret the arguments intended for a boot-app because its not a boot app.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot!